# поиск по dropdownlist

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, yii2

у меня есть таблица questions и category, и при заполнении таблицы questions надо выбирать category из предложенного в dropdownlist'e, и как мне организовать поиск по id category, чтобы найти и показать те questions которые нужно найти по id category.

```
 <div class="job-img-inputs">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <?php  echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 ">
        <div id="content">
         <div class="centered">
                <div class="main_content">
                    <div id="replace">
                        <?php foreach (\app\models\Questions::find()->all() as $data) { ?>
                            <?php if ($data['status'] != 0): ?>
                                <ul id="questions-list" class="questions-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="question-main-level" style="margin-right: 123px;">
                                            <!-- Avatar -->
                                            <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
                                            <div class="question-box">
                                                <div class="question-head">
                                                    <h6 class="question-name "> <?= $data['first_name'] ?>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <span>16.09.2016</span>
                                                    <?=$data['category_id']?>
                                                    <i class="fa "> Вопрос</i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="question-content">
                                                    <?= $data['question'] ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Respuestas de los comentarios -->
                                        <ul class="questions-list reply-list" style="margin-right: 123px;">
                                            <li>
                                                <!-- Avatar -->
                                                <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
                                                <div class="question-box">
                                                    <div class="question-head">
                                                        <h6 class="question-name by-author"><?= Yii::t('app', 'consultant') ?></h6>
                                                        <span>15.11.2017</span>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-reply"> Ответ</i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="question-content">
                                                        <?= $data['otvet'] ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
```

вот view надо здесь найти записи

Comment: то есть Вы имеете 2 выпадающих списка, и в зависимости от выбора в одном, должны подгружаться определенные варианты в другой? не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: нет, нужно вытащить те записи в которых выбраны именно эти параметры(id category)

Comment: человек задает вопрос и выбирает категории из существующих, и мне надо найти этот вопрос по категории

Comment: `\app\models\Questions::find()->where(['category_id' => $нужнаяКатегория])->all()` ???